# Running GUI application as root user

Tags: debian, kde, root, konsole

When I try to open a GUI application lets say KWrite in Debian KDE via terminal as root user I get this error:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I have used `export DISPLAY=:0` command as root user but still didn't work and also xhost +

Comment: I remember that when you run a command with `Alt+F2` there is a check option "run as a different user", look for that (I cannot test it because I don't use KDE now).

Comment: With Plasma 5.20 (but I'm on Arch Linux), KWrite doesn't run at all using `sudo`. Other applications may be executed with other users' privileges, including root, using `kdesu` from the `kde-cli-tools` package (it is based on `su` instead of `sudo`, thus requiring the password of the user you want to run programs as). I don't know what the implications would be, though, nor how different it would be from using `sudo`.